# How to dynamically fill a hiddenfield in django-rest-frameowork?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have two model's as:-

Model 1 `Location`:

- name
- organization
- coordinates
- address

Model 2 `FloorPlan`:

- name
- floor
- location(Foreign Key Location Model)
- organization

I am trying to create an endpoint for performing CRUD operation on the `FloorPlan` Model

Here is my serializer & view function:-

serializers.py

```
class FloorPlanSerializer(ModelSerialzer):
    class Meta:
        model = FloorPlan
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class FloorPlanListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = FloorPlan.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FloorPlanSerializer
```

Now the problem I am facing is I want to hide the `organization` field in the response, and would like to fill its value, from it's `location` instance(foreignKey) with POST or PUT/PATCH requests.

Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you need the FloorPan organization field if you want to use location's organization field anyway?

Comment: hey, I want to fill the `organization` field of FloorPlan models based on the organization of the `Location` field.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is have 2 serializers

```
class FloorPlanSerializerReader(ModelSerialzer):
    class Meta:
        model = FloorPlan
        exclude = ('location', )

class FloorPlanSerializerWriter(ModelSerialzer):
    class Meta:
        model = FloorPlan
        exclude = '__all__'
```

and then in your views override `get_serializer_class` to have different ones supplies depending on the method

```py
class FloorPlanListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = FloorPlan.objects.all()

    get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return FloorPlanSerializerReader
        elif self.request.method in ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH']:
            return FloorPlanSerializerWriter
        else:
            pass # you should probably throw and error here or handle it however you want
```

Comment: Hi, with this approach the organization field is visible in the HTML form. I wan to hide this field completely and take care of it in the backend.